# Code seems to not send the email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I seem to be stuck and I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies. I am fairly new to php so please bear with me.

Below is the code for the `signup.php` page, this is where new new users enter their details and once they are registered, an email must be sent to the email address that they provided.

The code does add the users details successfully to the database, but it does not send the email, nor does it show any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

```
          <?php

         //Calls the databse file
         require_once 'Dbconfig.php';

        //Checks whether the button has been clicked
       if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
       {

        //Sets the values from the text fields in the form
        $uname      = trim($_POST['txt_uname']);
        $usurname   = trim($_POST['txt_usurname']);
        $ugender    = trim($_POST['txt_ugender']);
        $upass      = trim($_POST['txt_upass']);
        $umail      = trim($_POST['txt_umail']);
        $udate      = trim($_POST['txt_udate']);
        $unum       = trim($_POST['txt_unum']);
        $uimage     = trim($_POST['txt_uimage']);

        //Validation
        if($uname=="")
        {
         $error[] = "provide username!";
        }
        //Validation
       else if($usurname=="")
       {
         $error[] = "provide surname!";
       }
      //Validtation
      else if($ugender=="")
      {
        $error[] = "choose gender!";
      }
      //Validation
      else if($upass=="")
      { 
        $error[] = "enter a password";
      }
      //Validation, 
      else if(strlen($upass) < 6 )
      {
        $error[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters long";
      }
      //Validation
      else if($umail=="")
      {
        $error[] = "Please provide email id!";
     }
     //Validationtation, checks whether the email is of the correct format
     else if(!filter_var($umail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
     {
        $error[] = "Please enter a valid email address!";
     }
     //Validation
     else if($udate=="")
     {
        $error[] = "Please provide your date of birth";
     }
     //Validation
     else if($unum=="")
     {
        $error[] = "Please provide your contact number";
     }
     //Validation
     else if($uimage=="")
     {
        $error[] = "Please upload an image";
     }      
     else
     {
        try
        {
            //Sets the value for the
            $umail = $_POST['txt_umail'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailAddress = :umail";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bindValue(':umail', $umail);
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($row > 0)
            {
                die('That email already exists!, please enter another');
            }
            else
            {   
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(userName,       
                  userSurname, gender, userPass, 
                   emailAddress, birthDate, contactNum, image)
                    VALUES(:uname, :usurname, :ugender, :upass ,
                     :umail, :udate, :unum, :uimage )");

                $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
                $stmt->bindparam(":usurname", $usurname);
                $stmt->bindparam(":ugender", $ugender);
                $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $upass);
                $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
                $stmt->bindparam(":udate", $udate);
                $stmt->bindparam(":unum", $unum);
                $stmt->bindparam(":uimage", $uimage);

                $result = $stmt->execute();

                ?>
                <script>
                alert('You have successfully registered, please ilog in');
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
                </script>

              <?php


                if($result)
                {
                    require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
                    $mail               = new PHPMailer();
                    $mail->IsSMTP();
                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
                    $mail->Host         = "localhost";
                    $mail->Port         = 25;
                    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
                    $mail->SMTPSecure   = ssl;
                    $mail->Username     = "smtp_username";
                    $mail->Password     = "smtp_password";
                    $mail->SetFrom      = "newsblock@gmail.com";
                    $mail->FromName     = "NewsBlock";
                    $mail->AddAddress($umail);
                    $mail->AddReplyTo("newsblock@gmail.com");
                    $mail->IsHTML   = true;
                    $mail->Subject  = "Successfully registered";
                    $mail->Body = "Thank you for choosing to become 
                                  part of the NewsBlock family
                                   You can now access our website 
                                    by logging in";

                    if(!$mail->Send())
                    {
                        echo "There was an error sending the email" 
                        . '' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Thank you for registering with News Block. 
                        Please login';
                        header("Location: index.php"); 
                      }
                    } 
                 }
               }
              catch(PDOException $e)
              {
                echo $e->getMessage();
             }
           }
         }  
         include_once 'Class.php';

     ?>
```

Comment: Have you a SMTP server on your PC ? If not, you should configure PHP (see php.ini) to use a mail sender. Example: sendmail.

Comment: Furthermore, if you're on Windows > 7 you might not be able to receive them poroperly using Wamp. You should then use something like [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)

Comment: It's very unlikely that `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` will work to port 25 on localhost. Try setting `SMTPSecure = false` - there's no need for encryption to localhost.